# Harbor Seal behavior and personality

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour, marine-biology, animal-psychology

I'm doing some research on Harbor seal behavior, but I haven't been able to find much on general behavior such as personality,  quirks, ect. Does anyone have anyone have any firsthand experience with harbor seals that could tell me what their general demeanor is? Are they playful? Curious? Shy? What are some behavioral actions that you see them do often? How do they react with their social groups? Do they have obvious hierarchies or do they mostly ignore each other? Any information is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Was this that question on Worldbuilding where they said people in the Biology SE could help?

Comment: Welcome to SE.biology! [This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301297609.pdf) looks like it might be useful

Comment: @DanPar yes it is

Comment: @user438383 Thank you this is perfect!

Comment: I think that the first to do is an ethogram about the behaviors of the Harbor seal...
Do you search for previous publications about Harbor seal behavior? See:
de Vere, Amber J., "Do Pinnipeds Have Personality? Coding Harbor Seal (Phoca vitulina) and California Sea Lion (Zalophus californianus) Behavior Across Contexts" (2017). Master's Theses. 273.
https://aquila.usm.edu/masters_theses/273